# Access Elements which are in a string-array within a List<>

Tags: c#, arrays, collections

I have several string-arrays, all with this scheme:

`string[0] = article number;
 string[1] = description;
 string[2] = amount;`

Now, the List containes ~50 of these arrays.
Now I wanted to know, how I can access to these values inside the arrays.

For Example:
I enter an article number into a textbox. 
Now the arrays should be searched for containing the article number in their "0" index.
How do I achieve that?
I tried something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i<List.length;i++)
{
   if(List[i[0]] == txtBox.Text;
   {
       doSomething();
       break;
   }
}
```

But of course that's not working well yet.

Comment: You can use List.Contains, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Of course it is not working well, this is all about Object Oriented Programming. You need a class

Comment: You may build a new class, let´s say `Order` with the properties articleNumber, description and amount, Then you create an array of those objects and search using the already mentioned solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems with you existing code:

1. To access an index within another index the [] need to go after each other not inside. i.e. [0][0] not [0[0]]
2. Because you don't have any {} for the if statement the loop will break after its first iteration.

Try changing it to something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i<List.length;i++)
{
   if(List[i][0] == txtBox.Text)
   {    
      doSomething();
      break;
   }
}
```

As other comments have pointed out it would be best to use a class and linq for this something like this

```
public class MyClass 
{
   public string ArticleNumber {get; set;}
   public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

The use linq to search it

```
var list = new List<MyClass>()
if (list.Any(i => i.ArticleNumber.Equals(txtBox.Text)))
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: You're right with the if{} thing, that's just an example, not my whole code. I forgot that in the rush

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you define a class like this

```
public class Article
{
    public string ArticleNumber { get; set;}
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; } 
}
```

whose purpose would be to hold all the information regarding the article, that now are stored in an array, which is not the best way.

Then you should create a list of arcticles:

```
var articles = new List<Article>();
```

in which you will add your articles.

Doing so, that you want would be the following:

```
// This would check if there is any article in your list, whose article         
// number starts with the letters in the txtBox.Text
if(articles.Any(article=>article.ArticleNumber.Contains(txtBox.Text))
    DoSomething();

// If you want to search if there is any article, whose article number
// matches the inserted number in the textbox, then you have to change the 
// above
if(articles.Any(article=>article.ArticleNumber == txtBox.Text))
    DoSomething();
```

If your intention is to use the article that may be found that exists, then we should change the above to the following:

```
var article = articles.FirstOrDefault(article=>
                  article.ArticleNumber.Contains(txtBox.Text));
```

or

```
var article = articles.FirstOrDefault(article=>
                  article.ArticleNumber == txtBox.Text);

if(article!=null)
    DoSomething();
```

The difference between this version and the first version is the fact that you know you could use the `article` if it is found, without querying again your sequence.